SimpleNotificationService Publish takes lot of time during high load
I've a .NET Core Web API that publishes messages to worker. When the load increases we see from telemetry that SimpleNotificationService.Publish from Amazon.AWS.AWSClientInstrumentation is taking more time like 10 seconds and sometimes more. The no. of messages that's been sent is only 6-7% of the quota. What could be causing the delay of SNS publish? Does memory / cpu usage affect SNS publish?

Did you check for throttling? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sns.html
